# Embedded field does not work after upgrading to Hibernate 5.0.6.Final in Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Having a embeddable class MultiLanguageText:

```
@Embeddable
public class MultiLanguageText {
@Field
private String textDe;
@Field
private String textFr;
@Field
private String textIt;
//...
}
```

And another class that uses this class twice:

```
@Entity(name = "T_AnotherClass")
public class AnotherClass{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long key;
@Embedded
private MultiLanguageText name;
@Embedded
private MultiLanguageText description;
//...
}
```

The fields got translated perfectly fine into "name_textDe", "description_textDe", "name_textFr" and so on with the spring version 1.2.7.RELEASE.

However to store LocalDate's I wanted to upgrade to Hibernate 5. I followed the process described here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2763#issuecomment-154419889

The process worked fine but the translation of the embedded fields stoped working *. I tried different implicit_naming_strategy and physical_naming_strategy, but non of them worked.

If I annotate the fields as follows it does work, but the process is somewhat cumbersome:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "textDe", column = @Column(name = "name_textDe", length = MultiLanguageText.MAX_TEXT_LENGTH)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "textFr", column = @Column(name = "name_textFr", length = MultiLanguageText.MAX_TEXT_LENGTH)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "textIt", column = @Column(name = "name_textIt", length = MultiLanguageText.MAX_TEXT_LENGTH)),
})
private MultiLanguageText name;
```

*Not working does mean I get an exception something along the lines of (as now the field gets mapped without the fieldname prefix and therefore the field exist twice):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: AnotherClass column: textDe (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:804)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:539)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 9):

To fix this in Spring Boot 1.4, add this to your `application.yaml`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl
```

From the [javadocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl.html):

> An ImplicitNamingStrategy implementation which uses full composite
>   paths extracted from AttributePath, as opposed to just the terminal
>   property part. Mainly a port of the older
>   DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy class implementing the no longer
>   supported NamingStrategy contract.

Comment: When you do this, you cannot use @CollectionTable anywhere because fields are mapped as parent_field_collection&&element_child_field. collection&&element part comes from the naming strategy and causes sql syntaxt error

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate official documentation says:

> If you want to have the same embeddable object type twice in the same
>   entity, the column name defaulting will not work as several embedded
>   objects would share the same set of columns. In plain JPA, you need to
>   override at least one set of columns. Hibernate, however, allows you
>   to enhance the default naming mechanism through the NamingStrategy
>   interface. You can write a strategy that prevent name clashing in such
>   a situation. DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy is an example of this.

Consequently, if you wish to have full JPA compliance, stick with your current implementation.